# How to get column of table with a self-referencing foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure shown below:

```
Id      Name    Sal     ManagerId
1       a       5000       2
2       b       7000       3
3       c       6000       1
```

I need output like this

```
Id     Name    Sal     Manager
1      a       5000      b
2      b       7000      c
3      c       6000      a
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You can join the table with itself as suggested in an answer below, or if all you need is the name, you can do a subquery to retrieve the manager name from the `ManagerId` column value (to decide which solution to use, do an EXPLAIN PLAN on both - you have to look up how to do that in SqlServer).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a self-`JOIN` to link one table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Sal, t2.ManagerName AS Manager
FROM TableName t1 INNER JOIN TableName t2 
    ON t1.ManagerID = t2.Id
```

If ManagerId is nullable you might want to use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Sal, COALESCE(t2.ManagerName, '<no manager>') AS Manager
FROM TableName t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableName t2 
    ON t1.ManagerID = t2.Id
```

Comment: @DavidG: why do you think that? That table's PK seems to be `Id` and `ManagerId` seems to be a FK to another table. But i'm not sure.

Comment: @DavidG: you're right, seems to be likely. I've edited my answer accoridingly.